# How can HTC VIVE developers share same space and test using different Vive sets?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, htc-vive

We have around 4 developers and we share a cubicle area. the base stations extend higher than the cubicle walls (for better tracking) but whenever 2 or more Vive stations are ON at the same time they interfere with each other and tracking gets problematic.

How do professional companies that work on big Virtual Reality projects solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The next generation of base stations and tracked devices won't have this problem, because the base station ID will be encoded in the laser, and a headset can ignore base stations it doesn't recognize.  Unfortunately this will require both new base stations and new headsets / controllers, and I've seen no estimate on when the next generation will be released.

In the meantime, the only solution is to find a way to partition your environment so that any given region is only covered by two base stations.  It's a pain, but you can cover a large area with a single pair.  If you only have 4 people in a confined space you might be able to set up so that you only have one pair of stations.  If that's not practical, you might look into mounting [barn doors](https://www.google.com/search?q=light+barn+doors) around the stations so that you can restrict their field of view.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can share a pair of base stations across many developers - that's how professional companies do it.